# Deleted Question - Reason?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

Just curious, why was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32519521/api-returning-class-name-instead-of-data) deleted?

Google Cached: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:EuDPsTkeVL4J:stackoverflow.com/questions/32519521/api-returning-class-name-instead-of-data+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk

I don't see anything that seems overly obvious that its a bad question other than being a little bit broad maybe. IMHO I don't think I would have given any action had this come up in a view queue.

Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: Didn't you get a notification for that? Doesn't it show some reason there?

Comment: No, I guess because I only answered the question and not the OP?

Comment: Ahh, then you will have to wait for some 10k user to come around and shed some light.

Comment: It was deleted in response to a flag.

Comment: @JonClements care to shed any more light?

Comment: @Magisch: 10k users can only see it was deleted by a mod. No reason provided. So, we're at Jon's mercy ;-)

Comment: @Cerbrus deleted by a mod is already more information then you get by seeing that its just been deleted. Afaik there are delete votes and the ROOMBA, no?

Comment: @Magisch: I wasn't sure if who deleted it was visible to users under 10k.

Comment: It was deleted by a diamond mod with no reason stated. Meaning it is apparently not something non-moderators need to concern themselves about.

Comment: Well in the interest of openness and sharing I would like to see the reasoning disclosed.

Comment: @Cerbrus Users under 10k just get a 404. Try opening it while logged out or incognito.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I deleted that question, and did so in response to a few flags. The asker had requested the deletion of this question and others because they contained proprietary code that they weren't allowed to reveal publicly.

Normally, it's standard procedure for us not to delete questions flagged like this if they'd received good answers. In fact, I declined their other flag requesting deletion on another question and in the other 20 flags like this I was handling at the same time I maybe deleted only one other question.

In this case, it seemed like the question and answer were very much specific to the code they were using and wouldn't benefit anyone else. I may have misread the comments, but they also made it seem like the issue was somewhere else. As a result, I thought little would be lost if this question was removed to satisfy their deletion request.

If you do think there is value in having this question on the site, let me know and I will undelete it.

Comment: Thanks brad, I answer more served as a best practice so happy to see it removed. Just interested as to why as it didn't in its on merit seem worth deleting.

Comment: @AshleyMedway Just to note, if it really contains proprietary code... your cached link is still available in the question.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes Not my code :)

Comment: And it's really paranoia as well, there's almost no application code in there. It's all boiler plate, and one (!) method call to a class that's probably proprietary code - which is not show. Probably a hyperactive legal team. But yeah, that'll teach them to create an example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes The internet does not have a delete feature.